# Замена типа в наследнике на производный тип

Tags: c#, .net, архитектура

Допустим, есть дженерик-интерфейс(`IRepository<T>`) репозитория с типичными `CRUD` операциями.

Есть дженерик класс `CachedModelRepository<T>:IRepository<T>`, который принимает на вход в конструкторе этот интерфейс репозитория, сохраняет его в поле и выполняет всякие кэширующие операции. Ну т.е перед тем, как дернуть реализацию интерфейса, он пытается достать данные из кеша. Т.е простая оболочка над интерфейсомю

И вот хочется добавить новое поведение. Например, какой-то реализации репозитория нужны доп методы, которые другим не нужны. Я делаю конкретное наследование `ISuperRepository:IRepository<SomeType>` и добавляю эти методы.

И теперь вопрос в том, как грамотно воспользоваться дженерик-классом кешем, зная, что те дженерик-CRUD операции не поменялись. Сначала думал, воспользоваться композицией, но в этом случае я не получу доступ к `внутреннем` `protected` словарю.

В итоге я сделал ссылку на репозиторий в классе-кеша в виде виртуального свойства:

```
protected virtual IRepository<T> _repository { get; set; }
```

И вот так вот стал работать в наследниках `SuperCachedRepository : CachedModelRepository<SuperType>,ISuperRepository`:

```
private ISuperRepository _SuperRepository;
    protected override IRepository<SomeType> _repository { get => __SuperRepository; set=> _SuperRepository=(ISuperRepository)value; }
```

Т.е родительский класс работает с базовым интерфейсом, а дочерний класс с производным интерфейсом.
Так вообще делают? Как-то не совсем естественно смотрится...

Comment: `public class SuperCache<T> : Cache<T> where T : SuperRepository`?

Comment: @tym32167 ну по моему то на то и выходит. Только в базовом классе хранится ссылка на базовый интерфейс, а в производном на другой. А если многократно наследование делать, то будет портянка. А в моем случае ссылку достаточно хранить в производном и все.

Comment: Ну только в случае дженериков не надо типы кастовать в коде

Comment: В целом так можно, почему нет? Но вариант `tym32167` мне больше импонирует.

Comment: `Я делаю конкретное насилование...` - это, наверно, описка при правке? Не надо насиловать репозиторий :)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko лол. Щас поправлю.

Comment: @tym32167 добавил больше конкретики. Мне почему-то кажется, что в моем случае так нельзя сделать.

Answer (score 5):

В принципе уже есть такой ответ выше, но я бы хотел немножечко расписать поподробней и сделать супер репозиторий также обобщенным.

Например, интерфейс

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Foo(T item);
}
```

Пример репозиитория

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public void Foo(T item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("REPO!");
    }
}
```

Кешу-декоратору тип репозитория также отдельно пропишем

```
public class Cache<T, K> : IRepository<K> where T:IRepository<K>
{
    protected virtual T _repository {get;set;}  

    public Cache(T repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }       

    public virtual void Foo(K item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cache!");
        _repository.Foo(item);      
    }
}
```

Супер репозиторий тоже сделаем обобщенным декоратором

```
public class SuperCache<T, K> : Cache<T, K> where T : IRepository<K>
{
    public SuperCache(T repository) : base(repository)
    {       
    }

    public override void Foo(K item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SUPER!");
        _repository.Foo(item);
    }
}
```

Ну и теперь можно строить цепочки декораторов

```
var repo = new Repository<int>();
var cache = new Cache<IRepository<int>, int>(repo);
var superCache = new SuperCache<IRepository<int>, int>(cache);

superCache.Foo(15);
```

Что выведет

```
SUPER!
Cache!
REPO!
```

Answer (score 3):

Делают и так. Подходы к проблеме существуют разные.

Мы, из-за того, что используем DI и применяем Autofac, остановились на решении с [интерцептором](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html) из *аспектно-ориентированного-программирования*.

Решение в Autofac основано на такой интересной штуке, как [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) из Castle Project, так что их можно использовать и в Castle, и наверное без больших сложностей, с другими IoC фреймворками.

Суть решения в том, что мы реализуем кеширование, как *декоратор* к репозиторию.

```
interface IRepository<T>
{
    . . .
    T GetById(Guid id);
    . . .
}

public class CacheRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> _repository;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public CacheRepository(IRepository<T> repository, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public T GetById(Guid id)
    {
        return _memoryCache.GetOrCreate(id, item => _repository.GetById((Guid)item.Key));
    }
}
```

Конечно, в таком виде нам приходится писать очень много кода, особенно, если у нас методы не только обобщённые, но и специфические в разных репозитория. Именно здесь нас и спасают аспекты.

```
class CacheInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public CacheInterceptor(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (invocation.Method.Name == "GetById")
        {
            var key = invocation.Arguments[0];

            invocation.ReturnValue = _memoryCache(key, item =>
            {
                invocation.Proceed();

                return invocation.ReturnValue;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь этот класс надо зарегистрировать в Autofac как интерцептор и использовать при регистрации любых репозиториев, как `IRepository<T>`, так и его наследников. Код получился не очень большой. В случае необходимости метод `Intercept` можно расширять. Недостатком кода можно считать другой уровень сложности, и то, что теперь надо следовать жёстким соглашениям об именовании методов, которые не проверяются компилятором.

Возможно, такой взгляд поможет вам посмотреть на проблему с другой точки зрения. Может быть, подскажет решение, которое лучше вам подойдёт.

Comment: Интересное решение, но безопасность типов теряется, что является жирным минусом=(

Answer (score 3):

Для начала выкинем из вопроса все лишнее. У нас есть интерфейс и его расширение:

```
interface IFoo {}
interface IFooEx : IFoo {}
```

И есть базовый потребитель интерфейса, который необходимо расширить так, чтобы получить доступ к расширению интерфейса:

```
class Bar
{
    protected IFoo foo;
}
class BarEx : Bar
{
    // ???
}
```

Для этого существует несколько основных способов.

### Способ первый - просто приведение типа

Это не самый быстрый способ, но и не самый медленный: он заведомо быстрее любых упражнений с перехватчиками/аспектами или рефлексией.

```
class Bar
{
    protected IFoo Foo { get; set; }
}

class BarEx : Bar
{
    protected new IFooEx Foo
    {
        get { return (IFooEx)base.Foo; }
        set { base.Foo = value; }
    }
}
```

Самое главное при таком способе - убедиться, что не существует открытых способов записать что-то в свойство базового класса, ведь любой такой способ приведет к нарушению LSP при подобном наследовании.

К примеру, нельзя подобное свойство делать открытым и изменяемым:

```
class Bar
{
    // неправильно
    public IFoo Foo { get; set; }
}

void Baz(Bar bar)
{
    bar.Foo = new FooImpl(); // БАБАХ, всё поломается когда сюда передадут BarEx
}
```

Но это не единственный способ все поломать:

```
class Bar
{
    protected IFoo Foo { get; set; }

    // неправильно
    public static void Baz(Bar bar)
    {
        bar.Foo = new FooImpl(); // лучше не стало
    }
}
```

Самое надежное - сделать свойство неизменяемым, а инициализировать его в конструкторе - тут уж точно LSP нарушен не будет:

```
class Bar
{
    public IFoo Foo { get; }

    public Bar(IFoo foo)
    {
        Foo = foo;
    }
}
```

### Способ второй - абстрактное свойство

Этот способ не имеет особых преимуществ перед первым, но он больше соответствует принципу "abstract or sealed", запрещающему наследование конкретных классов.

```
abstract class BarBase
{
    protected abstract IFoo Foo { get; }
}

sealed class Bar : BarBase
{
    protected override IFoo Foo { get; }
}

sealed class BarEx : BarBase
{
    private IFooEx foo;

    protected override IFoo Foo => foo;
}
```

В недостатки этого способа можно записать невозможность перекрыть (new) свойство в классе BarEx, поскольку в языке C# свойство не может быть одновременно переопределено и перекрыто в одном и том же классе.

### Способ третий - обобщенный базовый класс

Этот способ хорош вроде бы всем, но всё портит количество угловых скобок, которое в дальнейшем будет только расти...

```
class Bar<TFoo> where TFoo : IFoo
{
    protected TFoo foo;
}

class Bar : Bar<IFoo> {}
class BarEx : Bae<IFooEx> {}
```

Comment: `всё портит количество угловых скобок, которое в дальнейшем будет только расти` можно поподробней, чем плохи угловые скобки и почему они будут расти?

Comment: @tym32167 все параметры в угловых скобках обычно записываются в одну строчку, что эту самую строчку неприлично раздувает (привет Autofac с его `IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, ScanningActivatorData, TRegistrationStyle>`)

Comment: @tym32167 ну и не всем коллегам большое количество обобщенного кода будет понятно

Comment: Я имел ввиду, вот в моем ответе 2 параметра, вроде выглядят неплохо, Я пока не придумал, как там может третий параметр появиться. Ну и те два вроде не мешают, потому мне кажется этот вариант лучший, но, может, вы знаете какие то подводные камни или потенциальные проблемы?

Comment: @tym32167 а вы представьте, как при таком подходе будет выглядеть класс, который от этого репозитория зависит.

Comment: @tym32167 только вчитайтесь: `FooService<SuperCache<IRepository<Foo>, Foo>>`, а наследует оно от `ServiceBase<SuperCache<IRepository<Foo>, Foo>, Foo>`!

Comment: так классы же не будут напрямую зависеть от декоратора. Это скорее всего будет `FooService(IRepository<MyType> repository) {.....}`, а реализация репозитория будет собираться где то отдельно. Я к тому, что смысл зависеть от декоратора, если можно зависеть от интерфейса.

Comment: @tym32167 ну так скорость же, на одну индирекцию меньше и все такое... :-)

Comment: ну комон, это не аргумент :) Я просто почему спросил, я сам предпочитаю пилить декораторы, когда речь идет о кеше, потому и было интересно, какие тут минусы.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, с неопределенным типом для репозитория в женерик классе будет легче :

```
public class CachedModelRepository<T, TRep> : IRepository<T>
    where TRep : IRepository<T>
{
    protected TRep _repository { get; set; }
    public CachedModelRepository(TRep repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

в этом случае дочерняя инициализация будет выглядеть так:

```
public class SuperCachedRepository : CachedModelRepository<SomeType, ISuperRepository>, ISuperRepository
{
    public SuperCachedRepository(ISuperRepository repository) : base(repository)
    {

    }
}
```